# Iterate over `context.subscriptions` in vscode extension

Tags: loops, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I am trying to iterate over `context.subscriptions` using `entries` as follows -

```
for (let pair of context.subscriptions.entries()) {
   console.log(pair[1]);
}
```

But I get empty object. How to get the disposal object? I need to update object on certain condition. I have also tried using `forEach` loop and `JSON.stringify(pair[1])`

Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried on my extension and it worked.

Subscriptions are an array to which disposables can be added. 
That means that the developer adds his subscriptions to this array by running:

`context.subscriptions.push(disposable1, disposable2, ...)`.

Make sure that you explicitly pushed to this array using the above syntax.